# MySQL - GROUP BY with JOIN query

Tags: mysql, join, query, mysql-8.0

I am using MySQL 8.0.23

I have 4 tables: houses, intervals, discounts, and availability.

**Houses:**

```
create table houses
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(255) null,
    occupancy tinyint null
);

insert into houses (id, name, occupancy)
values  (1, 'Celopatra', 2);

+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | name      | occupancy |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Cleopatra |         4 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

**Intervals:**

```
create table intervals
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    house_id int null,
    start_date date null,
    end_date date null,
    adult_price int null,
    child_price int null,
    min_stay int null,
    max_stay int null
);

insert into intervals (id, house_id, start_date, end_date, adult_price, child_price, min_stay, max_stay)
values  (1, 1, '2021-02-01', '2021-02-05', 40, 30, 2, 4),
        (2, 1, '2021-02-06', '2021-02-10', 50, 40, 2, 4),
        (3, 1, '2021-02-11', '2021-02-15', 60, 50, 2, 4);


+----+----------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| id | house_id | start_date | end_date   | adult_price | child_price | min_stay | max_stay |
+----+----------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-05 |          40 |          30 |        2 |        4 |
|  2 |        1 | 2021-02-06 | 2021-02-10 |          50 |          40 |        2 |        4 |
|  3 |        1 | 2021-02-11 | 2021-02-15 |          60 |          50 |        2 |        4 |
+----+----------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

**Availability:**
This table is an expanded version of the intervals table. I am using the PHP backend to generate days for each interval period to query for availability. However, the price column in this table is not related to adult_price, child_price in the intervals table. It is a minimum deposit price for each day.

```
 create table availability
(
    id int null,
    interval_id int null,
    date date null,
    price int null,
    is_available int null
);



insert into availability (id, interval_id, date, price, is_available)
values  (1, 1, '2021-02-01', 100, 1),
        (2, 1, '2021-02-02', 100, 1),
        (3, 1, '2021-02-03', 100, 1),
        (4, 1, '2021-02-04', 100, 1),
        (5, 1, '2021-02-05', 100, 1),
        (6, 2, '2021-02-06', 120, 1),
        (7, 2, '2021-02-07', 120, 1),
        (8, 2, '2021-02-08', 120, 1),
        (9, 2, '2021-02-09', 120, 1),
        (10, 2, '2021-02-10', 120, 1),
        (11, 3, '2021-02-11', 130, 1),
        (12, 3, '2021-02-12', 130, 1),
        (13, 3, '2021-02-13', 130, 1),
        (14, 3, '2021-02-14', 130, 1),
        (15, 3, '2021-02-15', 130, 1);

+------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+
| id   | interval_id | date       | price | is_available |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+
|    1 |           1 | 2021-02-01 |   100 |            1 |
|    2 |           1 | 2021-02-02 |   100 |            1 |
|    3 |           1 | 2021-02-03 |   100 |            1 |
|    4 |           1 | 2021-02-04 |   100 |            1 |
|    5 |           1 | 2021-02-05 |   100 |            1 |
|    6 |           2 | 2021-02-06 |   120 |            1 |
|    7 |           2 | 2021-02-07 |   120 |            1 |
|    8 |           2 | 2021-02-08 |   120 |            1 |
|    9 |           2 | 2021-02-09 |   120 |            1 |
|   10 |           2 | 2021-02-10 |   120 |            1 |
|   11 |           3 | 2021-02-11 |   130 |            1 |
|   12 |           3 | 2021-02-12 |   130 |            1 |
|   13 |           3 | 2021-02-13 |   130 |            1 |
|   14 |           3 | 2021-02-14 |   130 |            1 |
|   15 |           3 | 2021-02-15 |   130 |            1 |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+
```

**Discounts:**
Type 1 represents percent discounts, 2 represents fixed amount discounts.

```
create table discounts
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    interval_id int null,
    discount_type int null,
    discount_amount int null,
    status int null
);

insert into discounts (id, interval_id, discount_type, discount_amount, status)
values  (1, 1, 1, 20, 1),
        (2, 1, 2, 40, 1);

+----+-------------+---------------+-----------------+--------+
| id | interval_id | discount_type | discount_amount | status |
+----+-------------+---------------+-----------------+--------+
|  1 |           1 |             1 |              20 |      1 |
|  2 |           1 |             2 |              40 |      1 |
+----+-------------+---------------+-----------------+--------+
```

**Final goal:**
I want to list available houses by their final price (after discount applied - discount may not occur as well) for the specific date period.
To achieve that firstly I am looking for available houses for the given date, after that I am sending the following parameters: sum, minimum start date, house id, and day_count to the `calculate` function.

Now, I was wondering is it possible to optimize this query. I thought, maybe instead of passing the min start date to calculate function, passing interval id directly would be much efficient.

How would you implement the same functionality in a better way? What would you say about the performance of this query?

[You can view DDL and DML statements via this link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c4cb589c17b558c0bcd881335e3ab00)

```
CREATE FUNCTION `calculate`(`sum` INTEGER, `minStartDate` DATE, house_id INTEGER, `day_count` INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE  interval_id INTEGER;
    set interval_id = (select id from intervals s where s.start_date = minStartDate  and s.house_id = house_id);

    SET sum = IFNULL((SELECT sum - sum * d.discount_amount / 100
                      FROM discounts d
                      WHERE d.interval_id = interval_id and d.discount_type = 1), sum);
    SET sum = IFNULL((SELECT sum - day_count * d.discount_amount
                      FROM discounts d
                      WHERE d.interval_id = interval_id and d.discount_type = 2), sum);
    return sum;
END;


select house_id,
       sum(a.price) as price,
       count(a.id)  as day_count,
       min(i.start_date),
       calculate(sum(a.price), min(i.start_date), house_id, count(a.id)) as final_price
from availability a
         inner join intervals i on i.id = a.interval_id
where a.date > '2021-02-03'
  and a.date < '2021-02-13'
  and a.is_available = 1
group by i.house_id
having day_count = 9;
```

Comment: How is this different from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284285/selecting-complex-data-with-joins)? I've tried to start to give you pointers - and now you just ask a new question apparently based on the old one - your SQL works! And you should (as suggested) use dbfiddle.uk - it has an 8.0.23 server!

Comment: @Vérace, I fixed my question - added DDL and DML right into the question body and updated the fiddle link. I know, my query works, but it does not return the required interval id.  I've changed the question description as well,  tried to explain the problem better. Can you please have a look at it again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting complex data with JOIN's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284285/selecting-complex-data-with-joins)

Comment: @nbk this was my question, but I deleted and recreated it with a better explanation and  DML, DDL statements.

Comment: @Shahin you can always **edit** your question with such data - and you can put any further info. in there as requested. Could you tell us what your **desired** result is from this data?

Comment: @Vérace, sure, instead of recreating I will edit from now on. I added the desired result section right after the explanation text.

Comment: @Vérace, they might have different min_stay data. Actually, I didn't post all of my columns for the sake of simplicity. There will be more different data for each interval.

Comment: How are you distinguishing between intervals 1, 2 & 3 which are contiguous and extend from 2021-02-01 to 2021-02-13? Why are they not all just one interval? Also, do you have check-out times?

Comment: `I didn't post all of my columns for the sake of simplicity.` - this is one case where simplicity is **NEVER** better than the full story up-front! Rewrite your question with **ALL** tables and **ALL** fields and what they mean! If we're flying blind, we can't help!

Comment: is there a good cause why the interval_id  is one and not say 1.2,3 or so

Comment: @Vérace, I rewrote my question with a full story. Please have a look.

Comment: @nbk, because the smallest date in the search range 2021-02-03 - 2021-02-03 is 2021-02-04 and it is located in the id 1 of intervals table. I rewrote my question, please have a look, it might be much easier to understand what is going on

Answer (score 0):

With the structure that you have

The C´GROUP CONCAT isd there because there could be more than 1 interval_id, that lies in  the minimum date

> ```
> select house_id,
>        sum(a.price) as price,
>        count(a.id)  as day_count
>        ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(interval_id ORDER BY interval_id) 
>           FROM availability 
>           WHERE `date` = '2021-02-03'
>           AND interval_id IN (SELECT id FROM `intervals` WHERE house_id = i.house_id)
>        ) interval_id
>
> from availability a
>          inner join intervals i on i.id = a.interval_id
> where a.`date` > '2021-02-03'
>   and a.`date` < '2021-02-13'
>   and a.is_available = 1
> group by i.house_id
> having day_count = 9
> ```
>
> ```
> house_id | price | day_count | interval_id
> -------: | ----: | --------: | :----------
>        1 |  1060 |         9 | 1
> ```

Comment: For one house, there can be only one price for the date. Let's say House Cleopatra can have only one price row for the day 2021-02-13 in the availability table.

Comment: you examp0le is too short and my query delivers that what you need in your initial request, axnad you sample fiddle with mire houses and what exact result you want